Error when saving marketing automation: Specify the details for all the elements in the campaign and try again
I can't get my automation active. When I click save, the error appears:
The automation campaign could not be activated. Specify the details for all the elements in the campaign and try again.
Can anyone please help me with how to activate my automation, what am I forgetting to do here?
Thank you so much!!


Is everything configured on the initial element of the flow?

Forgive me, but do you mean the funnel icon? I didn't even think to click on that, if that's the case ‍♀️

Yes, the funnel icon. Does it work when you select properties of the initial element?

Thanks Marek, I had added my goal AFTER the funnel. So now I configured my goal on the funnel icon itself. And that worked. ! :)

I had configured my goal trigger below the funnel icon. Instead, I configured the goal on the funnel icon, and I removed the separate goal trigger below the funnel.
Thank you to another user in the comments for helping me figure that out.
